# "Borei me'orei ha'eish" on havdalah candle holder

Tags: havdalah

If one has a havdalah candle holder with the words "borei me'orei ha'eish" written on it in Hebrew, would it be proper or improper to use it as a havdalah candle holder, considering wax from the dripping candle covers the letters and also wine gets on it.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you are concerned about? Why might one not use something for seemingly its intended purpose? Try to be as explicit as possible about your assumptions and thoughts so someone can best address your concerns

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Does the candle holder just have the words “borei me’orei ha’eish” on it, or does it have the entire Beracha?